# Toggle Button - OnCheckedChangeListener, Saving preferences always errors on NULL

Tags: java, android, onclick, toggle

I have a toggle button, That is working as expected. 
To test i have a Toast message, and they are both working.

However i have tried to store a the value of the Toggle to shared preference, I keep getting a error about Null object?

I have used this SharedPreference code throughout my app and i have never had an issue with it. 
But this is the first time i am trying to use a Toggle, Everything else is Buttons, Radio or sliders.

Am i missing something? 
If i comment out the PreferenceManager Store value, it works fine.

Here is the Code for my Toggle:

```
Switch myToggleButton = inflated.findViewById(R.id.switchon);
myToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if(isChecked) {
                preferenceManager.storeValue(packageName, true);
            Toast.makeText(context, "You have Enabled "+ appName + " Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
    else{
                preferenceManager.storeValueapp(packageName, false);
            Toast.makeText(context, "You have DISABLED "+ appName +" Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I also tried double checking null by running:

```
if (myToggleButton!=null){ //run code here }
```

But this was still the same

Here is the Error i am getting when pressing the Toggle On.

```
2020-05-14 12:08:35.360 23783-23783/com.enigamcodes.cutoutnotification E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.enigamcodes.cutoutnotification, PID: 23783
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.enigamcodes.cutoutnotification.Utils.PreferenceManager.storeValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.enigamcodes.cutoutnotification.Settings.NotificationColor$2.onCheckedChanged(NotificationColor.java:133)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this message

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.enigamcodes.cutoutnotification.Utils.PreferenceManager.storeValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

means `preferenceManager` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Thank you, Such a simple overlook, The Errorlog was just giving me no clue to what was causing the issue. 
For anyone else looking, it was resolve simply by adding: 
        preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(context);